# Is there any way to continue a job on Jupyter notebook since the last work session?

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I am using **Jupyter Notebook with R** to do some fairly lengthy analyses that require fairly heavy data. When I start the notebook the next day, I have to run the whole analysis from the beginning before continuing. This operation is very time consuming. Therefore, I am wondering if there is a way to continue the work on Jupyter notebook without having to re-run the whole analysis every day.  I know Dill for Jupyter Notebook with Python, but is there another solution for **Jupyter Notebook with R**?

P.S. I am learning to use R recently.

Comment: This is not related to Jupyter, but to the R framework you use. In Python/TensorFlow world there is the concept of checkpoints or pickle files. Both achieve what you mentioned in high level. You have provided just very high level details without mentioning the framework and storage you use.

Comment: You might be able to `save(..)` the current working environment to a file. In the first R code block of your file, check if the file exists and load if it does; in each subsequent code block, test to see if the file was loaded, and if not then recalculate the variables needed.